# Can we add custom labels using categories or other way on Y axis of scatter chart in fusion charts? If yes please explain how

Tags: fusioncharts

I am using angular api to render bubble/scatter chart of fusion chart i want to display weekdays on Y axis can anyone please tell me how to do that. I am unable to do this using categories as we do for displaying labels on X axis.

Answer (score 0):

Y axis is basically numeric. You can not achieve this by the default y-axis. However, you can do this by annotation. Here is a sample implementation.

http://www.fusioncharts.com/features/custom-values-and-annotations/